# Tiling window manager for ultrawide display

Tags: x11, window-manager

I just installed an ultrawide monitor.  My current window manager is XMonad. It only has two zones, whereas with an ultrawide monitor, three windows side by side would be better.

Which tiling window managers have this feature?   I'll try all of them, I'm looking for a list of options, not opinion on which is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

`i3` will support this by default.